# how to change footer content for certain pages only

Tags: theme-development, footer

need to change the Address content in the footer section for certain pages only

we are working in education domain the site has two main links one for ABC High school second is XYZ Nursery and primary school.

Here i wants to place two different address one for ABC high school and second one for XYZ Nursery school how can i make this two different addres in the site .

and also need to set the separate PRIMARY MENU for this .

Any one Suggest me for this asap

Comment: Hello! Welcome to WPSE, can you include the code in your question that displays the address? It's not possible to answer this in a generic way, not all themes contain an address in the footer ( some themes don't have a footer at all ). Use the edit link under the tags in your question to adjust your question to include the code that displays the address in the footer

Comment: As an aside, have you considered using a multisiite instead, and creating 3 sites, one for each school? Then they can all be configured differently

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress allows you to have multiple headers and footers which come in handy in situations like this. You can achieve this by simply creating footer files called something like "footer-one.php" and "footer-two.php" than where ever you would like to call the secondary footer in your theme file, like for example your "home-page.php" you simply include the name in `<?php get_footer('two');?>` I hope this helps.